# Vb .net memory leak?

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks

I have a class (too complex to post code), which I think may have a memory leak.  However the process workingset and virtual memory size suggest otherwise.

I create and destroy the class like this:

```
Dim vdt As ValidateDTC
        Dim prc As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess
        For I As Integer = 1 To 100
            Debug.Print("1:" & "WorkingSet64:" & prc.WorkingSet64.ToString & " VirtualMemorySize64:" & prc.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString)
            vdt = New ValidateDTC
            Debug.Print("2:" & "WorkingSet64:" & prc.WorkingSet64.ToString & " VirtualMemorySize64:" & prc.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString)
            vdt = Nothing
            Debug.Print("3:" & "WorkingSet64:" & prc.WorkingSet64.ToString & " VirtualMemorySize64:" & prc.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString)
        Next i
```

Once the class is created for the first time the workingset and virtualmemorysize are the same throughout the test.
My problem is that the debugger "Process Memory" graph climbs throught the test
If I put a break in the loop and snapshot the memory I can see all sorts of numbers increasing.

The class will ultimately be used in threads (via background worker).

Is there a problem, or not.

Comment: If your code is managed code (NET) only, It is not likely to have memory leaks. Do you use resources in your class? They may put load on memory if not managed properly.

Comment: Trying to follow memory usage in a GC language is inherently problematic.  The first problem is, the GC runs on its own schedule (unless you direct it to run, which is usually a bad idea, Microsoft has done a lot more research on optimal timing than you have).  The second problem is, just because you've released memory back to the GC, doesn't mean it's been released back to the operating system.  You might be seeing either no intervening GC run, or collected memory not returned to the OS with your test.

Comment: That having been said, there are situations where your usage may violate the assumptions of the GC, requiring more direct intervention if you're sure that the memory usage is sensitive enough to require the performance hit of a manual gen0 GC run.  The GC can handle short-lived objects really well, and it can handle forever objects really well, but it doesn't necessarily do well with long-lived objects.  Don't take my word for it, though... if you're interested in things at this level of detail, you NEED to read the low-level docs to make sure you're doing the right thing.

Comment: To answer your question, "Is there a problem, or not", I can't give a definitive answer without more details about `ValidateDTC`, but there is not a problem in the posted code.